# MS-Access VBA Date() works on one PC but not others

Tags: vba, date, ms-access

I am designing my first database from the ground up and I have learned a lot in the last few weeks. One thing that has been eating at me though is that on my login page I have a simple unbound text box with its control source as `=Date()`.

This works perfectly well on the computer I use most days, but any other computer in the facility I am working out of displays `#NAME?` instead of the date.

I have tried changing to `=Now()` and it works fine on all computers. Apparently only `=Date()` has issues. If the fields control source is changed back to `=Date()` I am informed that *The function you entered can't be used in this expression*.

I have checked the MS-Access versions and tried on a machines with and without access.

I really need `Date()` to work because it is used elsewhere in more vital areas of my code and I may not be able to use `Now()` in its place. Any ideas as to why this may not work on any PC besides my own?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with it? Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: Please show relevant code (not just one-liners).

Comment: The code was just that `=Date()`. But I think I figured it out. I went into my references and disabled some microsoft 1.0 reference that looked out of place and it works now... I am confused but relieved.

Comment: Thank you for the edit h3nrik. How do I go about resolving a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Date()** is controlled by the Visual Basic For Applications X.XX reference.  Make sure the reference is installed and any competing references are removed.

To do this, open the VBA window and go to Tools --> References and ensure the proper one is checked.

Comment: Ended up being the _MSExchange 1.0 Type Library_. I noticed that another project did not share this reference and its date field was working fine. Removed it and everything seems to be functional now.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is user's region and language settings for the date. I noticed this when I changed computers and my files wouldn't save anymore due to the slashes in the date. You should try the [format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Gg251755.aspx) function so that your dates always have the same format and can be used across machines independent of the user's settings.

```
Sub Foo()
    Debug.Print Date
    Debug.Print format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")    
End Sub
```

Output

```
7/23/2015 
2015-07-23
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise. All my computers are local and set up with all the same region settings, but I would never have thought to look there for a problem until you mentioned it.

Comment: While this may be of some value, it doesn't address the experienced issue.